# AADSTS90094: The grant requires admin permission

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

When I am trying to sign in to an powerbi embedded application and while granting consent, then  we get one of the following error. How can i fix this problem
[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqkLH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is User consent is disabled for the tenant.
To fix this issue we need to Enable user consent for the entire tenant (all users, all applications).
Follow these steps to enable user consent for tenant.

In the Azure portal, navigate to  "Azure Active Directory" => "Users and groups" => "User settings".
Enable the "Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf" setting and save the changes

An admin can grant permissions to the application - either for the entire tenant or a specific user.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot